# Wrong texture placement on object probably because of UV

Tags: texturing, uv, geometry-nodes

My problem that the texture that I generated using geocodes placed weird on the tip of all petals:
[image: Texture]

I've done some noob research in my guess it is because of wrong UV mapping. So I tried to do Smart UV project for all of them and actually it became worse (picture contains result AFTER Smart UV project and it is too late to undo :( )

EDIT: Just noticed that texture going not straight from root to tips but with some angle. And 100% that started after Smart UV project.

So how can it be fixed to make texture lines straight from root to tip of the petal?

Blender file: [Link](https://files.fm/u/ae6y4sddp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a seam along the petal edges to see if that helps.  Use Alt+LMB to select the edge loop, then UV-> Mark Seam.  Then do a standard unwrap.  I did it on the 4th row of petals here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CbaAQn5poHu6oIraJXLqjw37fRcUWcQT/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: There is no access to file :(

Comment: Try this one: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CbaAQn5poHu6oIraJXLqjw37fRcUWcQT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also tried your solution and seems it does nothing. Did you select edge in UV editor or on he model?

Comment: I selected the edges on the model in edit mode.  In the 'UV Editing' workspace (tabs at top of Blender), for each row I selected all and did a standard UV unwrap.   Below is a file with all the rows done, and a before and after render. [Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rV-itEiy3a1zSBypH9MfaUL2R6uELb8p/view?usp=sharing)  [render original](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hq749XCo8c58spiuzd5uQ_GOe-PJtPRr/view?usp=sharing)  [render new](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1naFs_RrWRZnH1s_T7-HGDOVzu1IYbDBq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you, looks like it is the solution!